# Find blocks of same dates in a vector and average over the corresponding block of data in another vector

Tags: matlab, date, vector

I'm new to Matlab and I'm looking for a solution to a problem of determining blocks of same dates in one vector and to average over the corresponding block of data in another vector.

Given is a vector consisting of several blocks of dates in the format 'dd-mmm-yyyy'. The blocks with same dates can have **variable length**. An example would be

```
T=  ['03-Jan-2013'; 
    '03-Jan-2013'; 
    '03-Jan-2013';
    '04-Jan-2013';
    '04-Jan-2013';
    '05-Jan-2013']
```

Each date in **T** corresponds to a data entry in another vector **H** (for simplicity same dates from **T** have here the same corresponding number in **H**)

```
H= [1;
    1;
    1;
    5;
    5;
    6]
```

The goal is now to determine the average of the elements of **H** which correspond to the same  dates and return a modified date and data vector **Tout** and **Hout** which would look like this:

```
Tout=['03-Jan-2013'; 
     '04-Jan-2013';          
     '05-Jan-2013']
```

and

```
Hout=[1;
     5;
     6]
```

where **Hout** represents the averaged values.

Both vectors are initially drawn from a textfile and can have a length of about **100k**. 
So looping is probably not the best thing to do.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unique` to get the unique dates and their multiplicity and `accumarray` to average over the ones that are repeated

```
[Tout,~,n] = unique(T, 'rows');
Hout = accumarray(n, H, [], @mean);
```